Continuous Drawing setting on grease pencil
I understand that there is a Keep Strokes / Continuous Drawing setting somewhere in Grease Pencil but I cannot find it no matter what.
Am I mistaken? where is it? Is there something else that will separate strokes when I lift the pen from the tablet?
Blender 4.1
